Trying to create a BEFORE INSERT trigger that takes the sum of a column in one table where the Name is the same and inputs it into a totals column
I am new to mySQL and as stated in the title, I am trying to create a BEFORE INSERT trigger that sums the values in NumTokens from Table 1 if the Name is the same, and updates a Totals column with the new total in Table 2.
I have tried multiple fixes, including using an INNER JOIN within the trigger to match the Names, using the GROUP BY function, and even setting the column in Table 2 itself to be a generated column. The last one is preferred, but I can't seem to get it to work. In any case, below is the code I have currently:
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER totaltokensinsert BEFORE INSERT ON Table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE TotalTokens int;
    Select SUM(NumTokens) totaltokens
    INTO TotalTokens  
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Name;
END$$
delimiter ;

I am not receiving any error, but the value is being returned as null when I open the table view in MySQL workbench. If anyone could help me figure this out I would be greatly appreciative! I have also added the current table with some sample data for both tables below. I would like it to return the sum of the values in the NumTokens column, inserted into the second table's "TotalTokens" column.
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Relationship</th>
<th>NumTokens</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Hoshi's Mom</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>Hoshi's Mom</td>
<td>-3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


If it is null, its not getting a value somehow.  Can you display the table for the tokens?  Perhaps its a datatype issue, you searching for '1' and it needs to be a value of 1 not the word of one (just an example concept)  Lets see what you got.  The DDL of Table1 would be helpful.  (note - workbench has a tab to create one for you to copy and paste)

There is no update in the trigger, you cannot store more than 1 value in a declared variable and do you really want to do this for every single row inserted? Please add sample data and desired outcome as text.

Sure! Here you go. Please be aware that I changed the name of the Relationship field to "Name" in this post. They are the same thing.  'CREATE TABLE suspiciontokenslist (
Relationship varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
NumTokens int DEFAULT NULL,
HoursAway int DEFAULT NULL,
DeceptionRoll int DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'

@P.Salmon Will do so now. Just give me a second to gather it.

He does have a point, I assumed you were using this to test the value before doing an insert, if a value was found, it was only selected and not inserted.  And like they said, it could be intensive if its done constantly, perhaps you could do batches of them in a an Event every 5 minutes or so instead of a trigger, unless the row needs to be inserted instantly when the change happens.

You want WHERE Name = NEW.Name rather than GROUP BY Name.

Why is this a BEFORE trigger? If you want to store the new total, it should be AFTER.

Thanks to everyone for their comments, but I have resolved the issue and no longer need assistance!
